# Настройка страницы в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день. У меня появилась проблема, совсем недавно начал работать с WordPress и столкнулся вот с какой проблемой:
Есть страница вывода категорий материалов. Как сделать так, чтобы на ней можно было вывести еще какие-то элементы кроме самих статей. Например меню справа или слева, может быть текст какой-то написать снизу или сверху и т.п. 
Сейчас я могу только в меню выбрать категорию статей и все. Она отображается в базовом виде.

Comment: Как вариант использовать виджеты. Зарегистрировать в `functions.php` новый виджет, далее вызвать его в темплейте и выводит туда что угодно!

Answer (score 1):

Делаешь еще один запрос с необходимыми параметрами и выводишь:

```
$new_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=other_materials' );
if ( $new_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) {
        $new_query->the_post();
        echo '<p>' . get_the_title() . '</p>';
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore original Post Data
```